# Swift FileManager attributesOfItem convenience functions not working

Tags: swift, macos, extension-methods, foundation

The documentation for the FileManager function attributesOfItem(atPath:) says the following:

"As a convenience, NSDictionary provides a set of methods (declared as a category on NSDictionary) for quickly and efficiently obtaining attribute information from the returned dictionary: fileGroupOwnerAccountName(), fileModificationDate(), fileOwnerAccountName(), filePosixPermissions(), fileSize(), fileSystemFileNumber(), fileSystemNumber(), and fileType()."

But trying to use these convenience methods (which I thought would be "extension" but Apple is calling them "category") does not work.

```
let fm2 = FileManager.default
let lPath = "/Users/Guest"
do {
    let aOI1 = try fm2.attributesOfItem(atPath: lPath)
    // aOI1 is a dictionary
    if let fS = aOI1[FileAttributeKey.size] {
        print("FileSize ",fS)
    }
    // The following does not compile
    //
    // Error: Value of type '[FileAttributeKey:Any]' has no member 'fileSize'
    //let fS2 = aOI1.fileSize()
    if let pP = aOI1[FileAttributeKey.posixPermissions] {
        print("posix ",pP)
    }
    // The following does not compile
    // Error: "This method is defined on NSDictionary, and may not
    // be available in this context"
    //let pP2 = aOI1.filePosixPermission()
} catch {
    print("Error")
}
```

I'm using XCode 13.3 with Swift 5.6.

Obviously I'm missing something here. The Apple documentation for `attributesOfItem(atPath: lPath)` specifically notes the convenience methods
defined on NSDictionary but although they exist I can't seem to call them
successfully. Perhaps it is better to just use the `FileAttributeKey.???` but I wonder how the Apple supplied "category methods" work.

Comment: Extension in Swift & Category in Objective-C. The utilities are on `NSDictionary` (more Objective-C, NSFoundation), and the Swift version of `attributesOfItem(atPath:` returns a `Dictionary<FileAttributeKey, Any>`. It's almost the same, but not the same, that's why.

Comment: Ok I'm confused on the dictionary type.  In the current Apple online documentation the prototype is `func attributesOfItem(atPath path: String) throws -> [FileAttributeKey : Any]`  This is in the FileManager (Swift) documentation for `attributesOfItem` and I have used that syntax so the return value from the prototype in the Apple documentation is a Swift dictionary.  But why did Apple document these methods (extensions,catagories) on the Swift language page or the method?

Comment: Copy/paste/forgot, or they didn't update it correctly? because in the end, `let attributesDict = try fm2.attributesOfItem(atPath: lPath) as NSDictionary; let size = attributesDict.fileSize()` compiles.

Comment: I'd guess there should have been something like that `extension Dictionary where Key == FileAttributeKey { func fileSize() -> UInt64 { self[.size] as? UInt64 ?? 0 } }` etc, (or a version with optional return value) for each keys...

Comment: No it was not a copy/paste issue.  The line quoted above is directly from the current Apple documentation.  I suppose it shortens the syntax a little from `let size3 = attributesDict[FileAttributeKey.size] as? UInt64 ?? 0` but the longer form contains more information, and there will be cases where treating a nil optional may be better with traditional `if let = ` semantics.

Comment: I meant copy/paste of the doc from Apple itself. In my opinion, when passing it into Swift they didn’t do properly/fully.